# How to add permission based on API level inside class to a static string

Tags: java, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova plugin that needs to add a permission depending on the API level

```
public class someClass{

public static String[] PERMISSIONS = {
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
};

public someClass(Context context, PluginDelegate delegate){
     if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29){
          someClass.PERMISSIONS.add(Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION);
     }
};

....
```

But then the build fails

```
error: cannot find symbol
        someClass.PERMISSIONS.add(Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION); 
                             ^
symbol:   method add(String)
location: variable PERMISSIONS of type String[]
```

How can I modify the static array of string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29){
        BackgroundGeolocationFacade.PERMISSIONS[2] = Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION;
 }
```

did the trick